# Do these equations apply to an object on a zip line or slope?

Tags: velocity, potential-energy

I was looking at the conversion equations for Potential Energy to Kinetic Energy to Velocity here:

http://www.ftexploring.com/energy/PE-to-KE.html

Would these apply to an object on a [zip-line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip-line)? What, if any, adjustments need to be made.

Answer (score 2):

These equations ignore friction which is critical in a zip line. Also the height not fixed as the cable stretches and sags. The exact equation of a lumped mass on a suspended cable is solved with two [catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary) curves, but to find the coefficients is a non-linear problem that requires numerical methods.